# Retornar parte inteira no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, conversão, inteiros

Qual a diferença destes métodos em JavaScript?

```js
console.log(parseInt(3.3));
console.log(parseInt(3.7));

console.log(Math.floor(3.3));
console.log(Math.floor(3.7));

console.log(Math.trunc(3.3));
console.log(Math.trunc(3.7));
```

Comment: Uma reposta que foi apagada continha um link interessante, vou deixar aqui: https://jsperf.com/test-parseint-and-math-floor

Comment: Interessante entre aspas, está comparando um caminhão com um carro. Não serve para a mesma coisa.

Comment: Mas mostra que, além de usuabilidade, os dois comandos tem diferença de performance

Comment: Sim, tem diferença de performance, se você mandar somar 1 em um inteiro e mandar resolver um cálculo fractal também tem diferença de performance, e não há relação entre eles, a informação não tem significado algum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O **[parseInt();](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)** vai transforma uma string (sequencia de caracters) em um inteiro
ou seja se você tiver uma string "as1" ele convere para 1 ou caso ocorra algum erro de conversão elete te retornará um NaN

O **[Math.Floor()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp)** sempre arredondará um numero flutuante (float) para baixo ou seja
3.966 vira 3, mas  diferente do parseInt ele não converte string em  numeros e vai causar erro de aplicação

O **[Math.Trunc()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trunc.asp)** te retorno o numero apos a virgula

São funções bem similares, mas  nem sempre pode ser substituida pela outra

```
var v = 3.14;
[Math.trunc(v), Math.floor(v), Math.ceil(v), Math.round(v)]
// print dos resutados

      t   f   c   r
 3.87 : [ 3,  3,  4,  4]
 3.14 : [ 3,  3,  4,  3]
-3.14 : [-3, -4, -3, -3]
-3.87 : [-3, -4, -3, -4]
```

Answer (score 7):

O [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) não deveria ser usado com número, até funciona, mas não faz sentido, ele analisa uma *string* e retorna um número inteiro se for possível a partir do texto analisado. Ele não é uma forma de tirar a parte do decimal, isto é apenas um efeito colateral. Além disso, [não funciona para todos os casos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/506307/112052).

[O `Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) faz um arredondamento, ou seja aproxima do número inteiro mais alto, então -3.7 daria -4 e não -3 como poderia esperar. Por padrão arredonda para zero casas decimais, mas pode usar a quantidade que deseja. Acredito que ele é um pouco mais lento se quer apenas a parte inteira e só deveria ser usado com uma quantidade de casas superior a 0 ou se for uma variável. O [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) faz o mesmo mas se aproxima do número mais baixo. E ainda o `Math.round()` aproxima de acordo com o valor, vai no número mais próximo.

O [`Math.trunc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc) despreza pura e simplesmente a parte decimal. Se é isto que deseja, e parece ser, é o mais adequado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).