# Por que "parseInt(0.0000005)" retorna "5" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, característica-linguagem

Mais uma vez, o JavaScript me demonstra um show de <s>horrores</s> mágica e dessa vez eu quero saber o motivo deste comportamento inesperado ao usar o [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

Por que `parseInt(0.0000005)` retorna `5` e não `0`? Como eu contorno esse problema?

Gostaria de uma explicação detalhada sobre este comportamento <s>mágico</s> estranho do JavaScript (pelo menos pra mim).

```js
console.log(parseInt(0.5))       // ok
console.log(parseInt(0.0005))    // ok
console.log(parseInt(0.000005))  // ok
console.log(parseInt(0.0000005)) // mágica
```

O interessante também é que se for uma *string* `'0.0000005'`, o `parseInt` funciona como esperado.

```js
console.log(parseInt('0.0000005')) // ok
console.log(parseInt(0.0000005))   // mágica
```

Comment: Isso é indiscutivel: _"JavaScript me demonstra um show de horrores"_ - independente do teor da pergunta kkkk

Comment: E o pior... imagina isso num sistema em produção gerando resultados inconsistentes quase que aleatoriamente?!?! Até identificar o problema... Quanto é `parseInt(0.000001 / 2)`? Ah, joga 5

Comment: Uma nota de rodapé, pra ser o "advogado do diabo": A pergunta me deixa dividido, pq `parseInt` não é para ser usado em número, pra começo de conversa, afinal, a única função do `parseInt` é justamente "obter um inteiro de uma _string_" (tanto que quando usou string deu certo). Se ja é numérico, não tem razão para usar essa função. Ao pé da letra, é mero erro de digitação, o formato é  `parseInt(` **`string`** `, base);`), mas me abstive de fechar por ter considerado pelo lado da "pegadinha" (traiçoeira por sinal, mas que não é exclusiva do `parseInt` e sim to uso indevido de tipos).

Comment: @Bacco Entendo seu ponto, mas achei interessante postar por um motivo o qual eu me identifico. Imagine alguem que começa a estudar JS, se depara com esse método `parseInt`, ela usa com, por exemplo, uma _string_ `'1.08'` e o retorno ela tem `1`, ai esse mesmo iniciante faz o teste novamente, só que com um número _float_ `1.08`, o retorno é o mesmo, logo essa pessoa pode ficar com o pensamento de que _"funcionou com números, então posso usar com string e numeros sem problemas!"_, como eu fiquei. Essa pegadinha que é o X da questao. Devemos destacar __nao usem `parseInt` com numeros!!!__

Comment: @Bacco o propósito da pergunta era esperar uma resposta do porque nao se deve usar numeros com `parseInt`. Até tinha comentado que nao tinha achado nada que explicasse isso aqui no SOpt, entao achei que seria de grande valor pra comunidade e __principalmente__ para quem está comecando a estudar JS nao cair nessa pegadinha como eu cair.

Comment: Editei a resposta enfatizando essa questão de não usar `parseInt` com números :-)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/294069/112052

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Resposta curta

A função `parseInt` serve para **converter uma string em um número inteiro**. Se ela receber qualquer coisa que não seja uma string, não é garantido que funcione da forma esperada (como você mesmo já percebeu).

## Resposta longa

Na [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) está descrito assim:

> *The `parseInt()` function parses a **string** argument and returns an integer*

E na [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix), assim:

> *This function produces an integral Number dictated by interpretation of the **contents of string***

Ou seja, a ideia da função é converter uma string para um número inteiro, por isso o ideal é que sempre seja passado uma string como argumento.

Se você passar um valor de qualquer outro tipo, primeiro ele é convertido para string, e depois esta string é avaliada. Na já citada [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-parseint-string-radix), podemos notar que é a primeira coisa que `parseInt` faz:

> 1. Let inputString be ToString(string).

<sup>Sendo que `string` é o primeiro argumento recebido por `parseInt`</sup>

E é aí que está o problema: nem sempre esta conversão para string resulta em algo que será interpretado como o valor correto.

No caso citado na pergunta, o que acontece é que valores muito pequenos, quando convertidos para string, acabam resultando em sua representação em notação científica:

```js
let x = 0.05; // este resulta em uma string "normal"
console.log(x.toString()); // 0.05
x = 0.0000005; // para valores muito pequenos, a string fica em notação científica
console.log(x.toString()); // 5e-7
```

E a string `5e-7` acaba sendo interpretada como o número 5, pois o algoritmo de `parseInt` vai lendo os dígitos, e quando encontra um caractere que não é um dígito válido, ele para e converte os dígitos lidos até o momento (e no caso, é apenas o `5`).

---

Vale também lembrar desta regra:

> - *If the input string begins with "0x" or "0X" (a zero, followed by lowercase or uppercase X), radix is assumed to be 16 and the rest of the string is parsed as a hexadecimal number.*
> - *If the input string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal).*

Ou seja, se a string começa com `0x` ou `0X`, assume-se que a base é 16 (caso ela não tenha sido informada). Em qualquer outro caso, assume-se que a base é 10, e como a letra `e` não é um dígito válido na base 10, o *parsing* só lê o dígito `5`.

---

No caso da string `'0.0000005'`, aí não ocorre este problema porque esta string, ao ser convertida para string, não é alterada para notação científica, permanecendo inalterada, e o *parsing* é feito lendo-se o zero e parando no ponto, resultando em zero.

Enfim, conforme dito no início e também nos comentários, a ideia de `parseInt` - e também de `parseFloat` - é de fazer o *parsing* de uma string, resultando no valor numérico que esta representa. Mas se você vai trabalhar diretamente com números, e não com strings, é melhor usar funções matemáticas para tal.

Se a ideia era pegar a parte inteira do número, por exemplo, o melhor seria fazer `Math.floor(0.0000005)`, ou então `Math.trunc`, ou `Math.round`, ou alguma outra função ou cálculo, dependendo de como você quer fazer o arredondamento (e [cada um vai dar resultados diferentes](/q/294069/112052), já que existem [várias formas diferentes de arredondar](/q/587052/112052)).

Usar `parseInt` pode até funcionar em muitos casos, mas como vimos, também esconde algumas armadilhas.

---

Por fim, esse problema também acontece com números muito grandes, que também são convertidos para uma string em notação científica:

```js
let x = 10000000000000000000000;
console.log(x.toString()); // 1e+22
console.log(parseInt(x)); // 1
```

Comment: AI!!!.......não quero mais programar em JS não... :(  Bora criar uma tag `bug-linguagem`

Comment: @CmteCardeal Aí já é outra pergunta, mas uma maneira seria `x.toLocaleString('en', { maximumFractionDigits: 20 })` - deve ter outras mais bonitas (ou não), aí acho que depende de cada caso e necessidade

Comment: @CmteCardeal Na verdade me confundi, pra fazer a conversão pra inteiro poderia ser algo como `Math.floor(0.0000005)`, já que você parece estar querendo pegar somente a parte inteira (arredondando pra baixo) - mas novamente, a "melhor" solução depende de cada caso

Comment: E eu aqui achando que já conhecia todas as pegadinhas do js...

Comment: @CmteCardeal A lição que fica é só utilizar `parseInt` e `parseFloat` com parâmetros do tipo String. Eles foram feitos para interpretar strings e não devem ser utilizados em outras situações.