# Javascript | Garantir que uma variavel seja Inteira (Int)

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, decimal, binary

Gostaria de saber se há como garantir que uma determinada variavel seja inteira!

desejo que o resultado de `Num / 2` seja `Int`, pois se for `Float` quebra o algoritmo.

Abaixo um código bem simples para validar uma idéia de converter numeros Decimais para Binario:

```js
function conversion(num){
    let dividedValue = 1;
    const binariNumber = [];
    let res = 0;
    while (num !== 0) {
        dividedValue = Math.trunc(num / 2);
        res = num % 2;
        num = dividedValue;
        binariNumber.push(res);
    }

    return binariNumber.reverse();
}

const numberConverted = conversion(25);

console.log(numberConverted);
```

Usei Math.trunc para retirar a parte decimal, funcionou, porém nunca vi ese método antes, será que existe algo mais "elegante"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc), `Math.trunc` faz exatamente o que você quer: dado um número, retorna somente a parte inteira, descartando as casas decimais. Então não sei o que você esperava ao perguntar:

> "*será que existe algo mais "elegante"?*"

Por que não seria "elegante" usar uma função nativa (que já vem pronta, junto com a linguagem) e que faz exatamente o que você precisa? <sup><sub>Na verdade, daria para simplificar outras coisas, que cito no final.</sub></sup>

Você até poderia tentar outros métodos, como `Math.floor`, `Math.ceil` e `Math.round`, que arredondam o número de acordo com determinadas regras. Você pode consultar a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math#static_methods) para mais detalhes, mas [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596503) existe um comparativo rápido entre as diferenças (reproduzo apenas alguns abaixo, só para você ter uma ideia - clique no link para ver o comparativo completo):

| value positivo | value = 5 | 5 < value < 5.5 | 5.5 <= value < 6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Math.floor(value) | 5 | 5 | 5 |
| Math.ceil(value) | 5 | 6 | 6 |
| Math.round(value) | 5 | 5 | 6 |
| Math.trunc(value) | 5 | 5 | 5 |

| value negativo | value = -5 | -5 > value >= -5.5 | -5.5 > value > -6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Math.floor(value) | -5 | -6 | -6 |
| Math.ceil(value) | -5 | -5 | -5 |
| Math.round(value) | -5 | -5 | -6 |
| Math.trunc(value) | -5 | -5 | -5 |

Enfim, para o seu caso, me parece que `Math.trunc` ou `Math.floor` seriam os mais adequados.

No [link já citado](https://stackoverflow.com/a/596503) ainda tem outras maneiras mais "esotéricas", como `~~valor`, `valor | 0` ou `valor - valor % 1`, entre outros. Mas eu já não diria que são elegantes, pois são difíceis de entender e gera um código confuso e/ou só para "parecer inteligente". Embora sejam curiosos, eu não os usaria em código de produção.

E antes que alguém diga para usar `parseInt`, sugiro que leia [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/506307/112052) para entender que nem sempre vai funcionar (para **o seu caso específico** não vai ocorrer o problema citado no link, mas ainda sim, me parece a ferramenta errada para a tarefa).

---

#### Outra forma de fazer

**No seu caso específico**, você quer converter um número para binário e retornar um array com os dígitos, então poderia ser assim também:

```js
function conversion(num) {
    return num.toString(2).split('').map(i => parseInt(i));
}

const numberConverted = conversion(25);
console.log(numberConverted);
```

Por fim, se o número for zero, seu código retorna um array vazio, mas o código acima retorna `[ 0 ]`, então eu entendo que o seu esteja errado para este caso. Afinal, o número zero convertido para binário resulta no dígito `0`.

---

#### Não sei se é mais "elegante", mas dá para melhorar

Outro ponto é que, em vez de adicionar os dígitos no final do array e invertê-lo, bastaria você usar o [método `unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift), que insere elementos no começo do array (assim não precisa do `reverse` no final). E também não precisa de todas essas variáveis auxiliares:

```js
function conversion(num) {
    if (num == 0) // tratando o caso específico do zero
        return [ 0 ];

    let result = [];
    while (num !== 0) {
        // insere no início do array (assim não precisa do reverse no final)
        result.unshift(num % 2);
        num = Math.trunc(num / 2);
    }

    return result;
}

const numberConverted = conversion(25);
console.log(numberConverted);
```

Lembrando ainda que nenhuma das soluções acima trata números negativos, mas não parece ser o foco da questão.

Comment: Abro um parêntesis sobre *"...outras maneiras mais "esotéricas"..."* que além de gerar um código confuso para fora do intervalo `[-2147483648, 2147483647]` deixam de funcionar gerando valores aparentemente sem sentido mas podem ser explicados [lendo a especificação](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-11.10) pois ao aplicar uma operação bitwise num tipo Number esse é convertido num inteiro de 32 bits e o intervalo `[-2147483648, 2147483647]` está dentro da faixa `[-2^32,2^32]` porém o JS trabalha com inteiros maiores `[-2^53, 2^53]` ou seja `[-9007199254740991, 9007199254740991]`.

Answer (score 1):

No JavaScript existem alguns métodos que podem ser utilizados para tranformar números Floats em Inteiro. O `trunc()` retorna apenas a parte inteira do seu número, descartando o que vem depois do ponto, você consegue olhar mais informações sobre esse método no site do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc).

Caso você queira arredondar para o número inteiro mais próximo, existe o método `Math.round()` como consta na documentação do [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round).

Com o método `Number.prototype.toFixed()` você formata um número, indicando quantas casas decimais deseja entre os parênteses, caso você deixa vazio, ele faz o arredondamento do número e mantém como um Inteiro, caso coloquei por exemplo: `Number.prototype.toFixed(1)` ele vai adicionar 1 casa decimal e assim sucessivamente. Você também consegue consultar mais informações sobre esse método no [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Existem mais métodos que lidam com este tipo de situação e tem comportamentos diferentes, indico você buscar no google algo como "arredondar variáveis numéricas no JavaScript".

Answer (score 1):

O Javascript não possui "Int", então qualquer número será Float, por padrão, inclusive o resultado do `trunc`.

---

Se sua função foi feita apenas para números inteiros, acredito que o BigInt (ou BitInt64) seja a opção mais adequada, já que ele é realmente um numero inteiro, e somente inteiro. Além disso, ele pode armazenar valores maiores que 2^53. Todos as operações de divisão será arredondado para baixo, como é esperado em qualquer operação com inteiros.

Seria algo como:

```js
function conversion(n){
    let num = BigInt(n);
    let dividedValue = 1n;
    const binariNumber = [];
    let res = 0n;
    while (num !== 0n) {
        dividedValue = num / 2n;
        res = num % 2n;
        num = dividedValue;
        binariNumber.push(res.toString());
    }

    return binariNumber.reverse();
}

var numberConverted = conversion("25");
console.log(numberConverted);

var numberConverted = conversion("18446744073709551615"); // max uint64
console.log(numberConverted);
```